# Decomposition of Partial Isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a paper and I don't understand how the operator is being decomposed. I've tried reading about different types of decomposition but nothing I read seems relevant:

(Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space.) Assume $P$ is a nonzero projection s.t. $P^\perp$ is nonzero. Assume $R$ is nonzero projection s.t. $R \leq P$. Suppose $T$ is a partial isometry s.t. $P^\perp T R \ne 0$. Now if we replace $T$ with $T U_R$ (where $U_R$ is a partial isometry with intial and final projections equal to $R$) then

$T =  
\begin{pmatrix}
  A & 0  & 0 \\
  B & 0  & 0 \\
  C & 0  & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$ where $A$, $B$, and $C \ne 0$ are operators.

Above each column is $R \mathscr{H}$, $P \mathscr{H} \ominus R \mathscr{H}$, and $P^\perp \mathscr{H}$ respectivly. (I don't know the syntax to add this to the matrix.)

I'm not sure what this decomposition means or how they arrived at it.